# Eclipse says 'Class not found' even though the classes are available

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse

In Eclipse UI, I got the following problem,

[image]

If you see left side, the classes are available. I am able to build using Maven and run it successfully. But this Eclipse error highlighting is really annoying.

I am using Eclipse Indigo SR2 and installed Spring Tool Suite. Please help me on fixing this issue. Thanks.

Comment: try importing com.beatle.model.* and see what happens

Comment: It worked :). I am wondering what could be the problem?

Comment: @Satya, please enter this as answer. So I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try importing com.beatle.model.* and see what happens